# How to save and close tabs with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: tabs, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I always find myself having at least 10 tabs open in VS Code. I easily get lost in all my tabs and I feel it kills productivity.

Is there a fast key binding to save and close a tab?

Answer (score 8):

One way to save and close an editor at the same time would be with a macro.  Using the [multi-command macro extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), put this into your settings.json:

```json
"multiCommand.commands": [   
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.saveAndCloseEditor",
      "sequence": [
        "workbench.action.files.save",
        "workbench.action.closeActiveEditor",
      ]
    }
]
```

and I used this keybinding (keybindings.json):

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+w",
  "command": "-workbench.action.closeActiveEditor"
},


{
  "key": "ctrl+w",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.saveAndCloseEditor" }
},
```

First, removing the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> which would close the current tab/editor - but if the file was dirty would stop to prompt to save.

Second, use the same  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to trigger the macro.  Now the editor is saved first and then closed at once with no prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you press Ctrl-f4 on unsaved editor, there will be a save-prompt.

You can check the keybindings in VSCode or in this manual https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Answer (score 1):

To increase productivity with opened tabs, I use [stack-tabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kylepaulsen.stack-tabs) so that the most recently opened tabs are moved to the left automatically. This is very useful to not get lost because the tabs you are working on are often the most recent.

I also use [bookmarks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks) to navigate more easily between the code.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `Pin` feature to keep most important tabs at the left. Then I use `alt + 1`, `alt + 2`(, etc..) to quickly select the 1, 2(, etc..) tab at the left.

I use the command "Close All Editors" (`@command:workbench.action.closeAllEditors`) to close all unpinned tabs at once.

I have set shortcuts to Pin/Unpin & close a pinned tab so I can easily managed pinned tabs.